# VBA Visio change Ribbon value on the fly

Tags: vba, ribbon

Under Microsoft Visio, I can amend Ribbon menu but I need to modify value on the fly when for instance an user clicks on shape.
To simplify comprehension, see below code I have done which creates a new menu called 'test' under which there is a button. Objective is when clicking on this button , it should change label name of the button. I cannot make it works.
Note that I didnt put callback functions onto module as I have to use specific functions part of the global.

See below my code. You can just copy / paste it and test it.
Hope someone could highlight the mistake or a workaround ?

```
Option Explicit

Dim ribbonUI As IRibbonUI
Dim loggedIn As Boolean

Public Sub CreateRibbon()
Dim ribbonXML As String

ribbonXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"" onLoad=""ribbonLoaded"">"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   <ribbon startFromScratch=""false"">"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <tabs>"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <tab id=""TB01"" label=""Test"">"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "            <group id=""GR01"" label=""Test Labelling"">"

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "                <button id=""Login"" getLabel=""ThisDocument.getLabelLogin"" size=""large"" imageMso=""HappyFace"" onAction=""ThisDocument.OnActionLogin""/>"

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "            </group>"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </tab>"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </tabs>"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   </ribbon>"
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</customUI>"

ActiveDocument.CustomUI = ribbonXML
End Sub

Public Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
Call CreateRibbon
End Sub

Public Sub ribbonLoaded(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set ribbonUI = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub OnActionLogin(control As IRibbonControl)
If loggedIn = True Then
   loggedIn = False
Else
   loggedIn = True
End If

MsgBox ("you press the buttton. Value=" & loggedIn)

ribbonUI.Invalidate
End Sub

Public Sub getLabelLogin(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
If loggedIn = True Then
   returnedVal = "Value True"
Else
   returnedVal = "Value False"
End If
MsgBox "New value=" & loggedIn & " " & control.id
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find the mistake !! The 'onload' function never started. I had 'ThisDocument.' on line :

```
ribbonXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"" onLoad=""ThisDocument.ribbonLoaded"">"
```